# Powershell Exchange EWS script authentication using Oauth unable to use a save password hash file

Tags: powershell, authentication, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Normally for scheduled scripts I save a hash file to disk for the credentials to be used by the script as follows:

```
$Credential = Get-Credential Admin@domain.com 
$Credential.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content "C:\admin.pwd" $Username = "Admin@domain.com" 
$Password = Get-Content "C:\admin.pwd" -ErrorAction stop | ConvertTo-SecureString
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username,$Password)
```

The following Oath token request works if the password element in the Body is entered in plain text, but it is not working if I use the variable $Credential.Password . Is there a way to get this to work, or secure the password otherwise?

The Error that the below token request generatedes:

Error: Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password..."error_uri":"login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50126"}

```
## Request an access token

# Define AppId, secret and scope, your tenant name and endpoint URL
$AppId = 'AppIdHere'
$AppSecret = 'AppSecretHere'
$Scope = "https://outlook.office365.com/.default"
$TenantName = "Domain.onmicrosoft.com"
$Url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token"

# Add System.Web for urlencode
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

# Create body
$Body = @{
    client_id = $AppId
    client_secret = $AppSecret
    scope = $Scope
    grant_type = 'password'
    username = 'Admin@domain.com'
    password = $Credential.Password
}

# Splat the parameters for Invoke-Restmethod for cleaner code
$PostSplat = @{
    ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    Method = 'POST'

    # Create string by joining bodylist with '&'
    Body = $Body
    Uri = $Url
}

# Request the token for user!
$Request = Invoke-RestMethod @PostSplat

$Request.access_token

##########
```

===========================

**Updated script based on answer from thepip3r, and Microsoft support**:

Password and secret are passed in plain text on the wire, but are not
exposed in the script, and have a degree of security saved as hash
files

Adjusted to not save the password or secret into variables to
increase security from attacks that can gain access to memory (MS
support recommended)

Option to use a certificate for the Azure Registered App rather than
an App Secret, to increase security on the wire

Alternative option is to use "*Azure Automation*", which allows to
run scripts from within O365, which should be much more secure.
Another possible alternative may be Azure Functions.

```
# One time AppID\Secret hash save to file:
## $AppCredential = Get-Credential 'AppIdHere'
## $AppCredential.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content "C:\App.pwd" 

# One time Admin hash save to file:
## $Credential = Get-Credential admin@domain.com
## $Credential.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content "C:\admin.pwd" 

$AppId = 'AppIdHere'
$AppS = Get-Content "C:\App.pwd"  | ConvertTo-SecureString
$AppCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($AppId,$AppS)

$Username = "admin@domain.com"
$Password = Get-Content "C:\admin.pwd" | ConvertTo-SecureString
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username,$Password)        

### Request an access token ###

$Scope = "https://outlook.office365.com/.default"
$TenantName = "usablelife.onmicrosoft.com"
$Url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token"

# Add System.Web for urlencode
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

# Request the token!
$Request = Invoke-RestMethod -Body @{
    client_id = $AppId
    client_secret = $AppCredential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
    scope = $Scope
    grant_type = 'password'
    username = $Username 
    password = $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
} `
-ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' `
-Method 'POST' `
-Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So... I'm going to provide this as an answer because I want people to understand this being an example the problem with storing a password in a file (even as a ciphertext string value) with Get-Credential.

@mbromb, this will give you a way to *test* whether or not the value you're retrieving is the proper value:

on your $Credential object (last line), run:  `$Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password`

This will be the *PLAINTEXT* value of whatever you put into the prompts with Get-Credential initially.  So, you can verify if after getting it initially, writing it to a file, reading it back in, and converting it to a securestring object worked as intended.

To try and draw a more straight-line to this problem:  if I find your 'admin.pwd' file, it's extremely trivial to produce the plaintext from it.

Caveat:  You can secure this value by supplying a protected key for this encryption process using either the -Key or -SecureKey properties on the ConvertTo/From-SecureString cmdlets.  Key takes a byte array (preferably cryptographically random with sufficient entropy for your needs) and SecureKey accepts a string (password) and generates the byte array from your password.

Caveat-to-the-caveat:  If you're already trying to store the password to a file, password protecting the stored-password probably isn't the right answer...

Comment: Thank you!  I've updated the question with the adjusted script. It seems that it will work well.

I've set `$Pass = $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password`, and send that as the password.  It needs the password in plain text rather than a secure string, which makes sense.  I'm doing the same for the AppID\Secret, so neither user password, or App Secret are exposed in plain text in the script.  I'm also finding that I cannot do anything with a PWD file unless I'm using the user that created it, which is how that's worked when using the hashed PWD file for scheduled scripts.

Comment: And now that I think about it, the script is now passing the admin password in plain text across the wire.  That doesn't seem secure, but I can't get it to work with a secure string.

Comment: And I've found this, 

[link](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/password/): 
"Because the client application has to collect the user's password and send it to the authorization server, it is not recommended that this grant be used at all anymore."

[link](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-13#section-3.4):
"The resource owner password credentials grant MUST NOT be used"

So it seems I"m back to square one.

Comment: Does this code snippet help?  Look at the code towards the bottom where they use a different credential object:  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/learn-to-use-the-exchange-web-services-with-powershell/

Comment: That describes how to  work with mailboxes using EWS, which is what my scripts do.  What I need to do is change how the scripts authenticate in order to do that work.  Currently, I use Basic auth which is being decommissioned, and so it's necessary to switch to Oauth, which is why I'm here asking about getting a token securely.  I've opened a case with MS, adn will post what comes of it.  Thank you

Comment: **Script updated in the Question area**: - Password & secret passed in plain text on wire, but not exposed in script, and somewhat secure saved as hash files - Adjusted to not save password or secret in variables to increase security from attacks that can gain access to memory - Option to use a certificate for the Azure Registered App rather than an App Secret, to increase security on the wire - Alternative option is to use "Azure Automation", which allows to run scripts from within O365, which should be much more secure. Another possible alternative may be Azure Functions.